# Declaring a var, placing it in a query and using the output of the query?

Tags: query, variables, post-meta

So i'm wondering if it's possible to declare a `variable` that you'd place in a `query` to then use it in a `update_post_meta` function?

This is how I tried to do it.

First off I made a connection to another db where the info comes from to than query out the results(Tested in SQL works) like so:

```
 global $newdb;
  $newdb = new wpdb('....', '....', '....', '....');
  $newdb->show_errors();
  $column1  = "member_name";
  $column2  = "memberID";
  $meta_key = "field_12312ewrwe12312";
  $result   = $newdb->get_results("SELECT ".$column1.",".$column2."  FROM members");  
  $columnq  = $newdb->get_results("SELECT ".$column1." FROM members");
  $columnq2 = $newdb->get_results("SELECT ".$column2." FROM members");
```

Most notably `$columnq` and `$columnq2`.

I than used the query strings to fetch the data in a `update_post_meta` function/button and thought this should've worked since blankly putting `$column1` and `$column2` after clicking submit only adds the actual `value` it contains so say I get a new post called `member_name` each time I submit.

The code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Test" id="submit" name="submit">
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $postargs = array(
            'post_title'   => $columnq,
            'post_status'  => 'draft',
            'post_type'    => 'bedrijf'
        );

        $thisid = wp_insert_post ( $postargs, true);

        if ( is_wp_error($thisid) ) {
            return get_error_codes();
        } else {  
            update_post_meta( $thisid, $meta_key, $columnq2);
        }
    }
       var_dump($columnq);
       var_dump($columnq2);
    ?> 

</form>
```

P.S. Yes `var_dump` shows the correct information.

EDIT:
Added the `var_dump`.
The information output by the `var_dump` is far to many, instead I will post a piece of both.

Columnq:

```
array(460) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1026 (1) { ["member_name"]=> string(18) "Some information" }
```

Columnq2:

```
array(460) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1486 (1) { ["memberID"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

EDIT2:
I also placed the `var_dump` into the button itself(Under `update_post_meta`) and it output the exact same and correct information. Yet in the back code it adds only one post which is empty with also `(no title)` as name.

Comment: Can we see the expected values of those variables and the actual values of the variables when doing the form submission? You say var_dump shows the correct information, can you post that information, as well as where/when the var_dump was called?

Comment: Edited it the bottom part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is confusing:

```
$result   = $newdb->get_results("SELECT ".$column1.",".$column2."  FROM members");  
$columnq  = $newdb->get_results("SELECT ".$column1." FROM members");
$columnq2 = $newdb->get_results("SELECT ".$column2." FROM members");
```

You should only need the first of those or the last two (with one alteration).

Secondly, [`get_results`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database) will return an array or an object (default), so using it as you do here isn't going to work:

```
'post_title'   => $columnq,
```

`post_title` does not accept an array or an object as a value.

If you want to retrieve a single string value from the database use `get_var`. Then this will work:

```
$columnq  = $newdb->get_row("SELECT ".$column1." FROM members");
$postargs = array(
        'post_title'   => $columnq,
        'post_status'  => 'draft',
        'post_type'    => 'bedrijf'
);
```

To retrieve a single row use `get_row` and with proper syntax:

```
$result   = $newdb->get_results("SELECT ".$column1.",".$column2."  FROM members");  
$postargs = array(
        'post_title'   => $result[$column1],
        'post_status'  => 'draft',
        'post_type'    => 'bedrijf'
);
```

But your code is still a bit confusing as you appear to be retrieving all rows from your external database/table but trying to use those rows as if they were a single row.

```
$columnq  = $newdb->get_results("SELECT {$column1},{$column2} FROM members");
foreach ($columnq as $c) {
  $postargs = array(
      'post_title'   => $c->column1,
      'post_status'  => 'draft',
      'post_type'    => 'bedrijf'
  );
  // code to insert post
}
```

Comment: `get_var` was exactly what I needed although what happens is that it only inserts the first column and not all the other column, is there a reason for this? How is it that i'm retrieving all rows? I'm pretty sure that stating the rows you want after `SELECT` makes sure you only select those rows? I'm inexperienced that's why the code may look so confusing for you.

Comment: There is a difference between "all rows" and "all columns". The items listed after `SELECT` are the columns, but those columns will be returned for all rows in the table. I gave you several examples. `get_var` only retrieves the single value. Look at the `get_row` example, or the loop in the last sample.

Comment: Sorry I failed to see the last loop before commenting that but actually did try it out and it worked absolutely great. Appearently `get_var` was also what I needed according to the loop you gave me last as `get_row` returned me an empty title. It couldn't have been differently too I think because after all a variable was called in the query. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question why is my `update_post_meta` not working? I'm trying to insert the `column2` there but apparently the field I selected remains empty. Now i'm not sure how to test `update_post_meta` but I am sure the `meta_key` is right and that the column is right too, I by the way changed the line like so because it wasn't working either way(to test): `update_post_meta( $thisid, $meta_key, $c->memberID);`

Comment: Sorry can't edit my comment yet. I can confirm that the `update_post_meta` DOES insert in the `database` but it doesn't show so on the `post` itself(along with the `args` that you solved for me earlier).

Comment: What is the key name?

Comment: The key itself in the database is called `ID` the key's ID however(What I declared as `meta_key`) is `field_12312ewrwe12312`.